# Why does this method not return whether the area is bigger than the parameter cubed?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm working on a Minecraft plugin to protect an area. I have area class which is created after the player selects 3 blocks, and this area class has a method named "`tooBig`", it is used for detecting if the area is bigger than if "`block^3`". The problem is that this method always returns `false`.

```
public boolean tooBig(int i) {
    boolean bo1, bo2, bo3;
    bo1 = Math.abs(b1.getX() - b2.getX()) > i;
    bo2 = Math.abs(b1.getZ() - b2.getZ()) > i;
    bo3 = Math.abs(b1.getY() - b3.getY()) > i;
    return bo1 && bo2 && bo3;
}
```

`b1`, `b2`, and `b3` are `Block` objects.

Answer (score 7):

Your use of variables are inconsistent.

```
public boolean tooBig(int i) {
    boolean bo1, bo2, bo3;
    bo1 = Math.abs(b1.getX() - b2.getX()) > i;
    bo2 = Math.abs(b1.getZ() - b2.getZ()) > i;
    bo3 = Math.abs(b1.getY() - b3.getY()) > i;
    return bo1 && bo2 && bo3;
}
```

Your algorithm is incorrect altogether. The formula of calculating the volume of a [rectangular cuboid region](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboid#Rectangular_cuboid) is

```
Base (Length * Width) * Height
```

Where the **Length**, **Width** and the **Height** of the cuboid would be *the distance from the maximum point through an axis to the minimum point* instead of randomly two points subtracting. So the correct code for getting the area would be:

```
public boolean tooBig(int i) {
    int minX = Math.min(Math.min(b1.getBlockX(), b2.getBlockX()), b3.getBlockX());
    int maxX = Math.max(Math.max(b1.getBlockX(), b2.getBlockX()), b3.getBlockX());
    int minY = Math.min(Math.min(b1.getBlockY(), b2.getBlockY()), b3.getBlockY());
    int maxY = Math.max(Math.max(b1.getBlockY(), b2.getBlockY()), b3.getBlockY());
    int minZ = Math.min(Math.min(b1.getBlockZ(), b2.getBlockZ()), b3.getBlockZ());
    int maxZ = Math.max(Math.max(b1.getBlockZ(), b2.getBlockZ()), b3.getBlockZ());
    
    int area = (maxX - minX) * (maxY - minY) * (maxY - minY);
}
```

To make it work:

```
return area > Math.pow(i, 3);
```

See also:

```
Block.getBlockX()
```

Comment: By the way, limiting the volume of the area is not secure, because player could make 1x1x[max_volume] area, which can be used for privating large distance areas.

Comment: @Heavy That's true, but the original question included specification "it is used for detecting if the area is bigger than i "block^3"."; As such, additional checks can be performed by playing around with `maxX`, `minX` and alike variables (which I created for this purpose).

Answer (score 1):

This function will return `true` only if area's width, length and height more than `i` *at the same time*.

Maybe you should use `return (bo1 || bo2 || bo3);` so the function will return `true` if at least one of the dimensions exceeds the limit.

Comment: It was noted in the answer as an update "why player should select 3 blocks, when 2 blocks is enough?" Since this is likely to solicit discussion rather than completing the question / answer, I've moved it here into a comment.